# How can I know the Product key of my original Windows 7 (HP dv6 laptop) ?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hp-pavilion, product-key, oem

I have a HP dv6 laptop which has come with original Windows 7 home premium 64 bit. The product key is on the sticker under the laptop. But, the sticker is faded away, so I cannot read all the characters (I can only read 10 characters out of 25). I tried two third-party software (Belarc, Magic jelly bean) which gave me product key that does NOT match with the sticker one.

How can I get the product key (the sticker one)?

P.S.: From the screenshot, it seems that my windows 7 installation is an OEM installation by HP.  (correct me if I am wrong)

Please help..... :([image: this is a screenshot of the system properties]

Comment: Belarc is almost certainly giving the corporate key. Installations, which are done in bulk, are typically done with a manufacturer's corporate key rather than the sticker key, which is only an individual key for that particular machine.

Comment: As a genuine question, why do you think you need the sticker key? The corporate key should be a valid multiple use key.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools such as the free [Nisoft ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) that will show the current Windows key (and ID), BIOS OEM key etc.

Comment: How to retrieve/know the key which is on the sticker?

Comment: It should be the same as shown by ProdKey... compare the characters that are visible on the tag with that shown in the application.

Comment: I tried ProduKey. It does NOT give me the key which is on the sticker. It gives a different key..

Comment: Is there anyone who can give me a solution so that I can find the Sticker key?